# Difference between workbook and _workbook

Tags: c#, excel

while writing EXCEL files we can notice there are application ,_application ,workbook,_workbooks similarly worksheet also,
though i have read somewhere those are quite same no difference!! if it is true then why separate methods.

please do help me to know
thank you

Comment: Most likely, backward compatibility/legacy.

Comment: Check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73b4b653-cc9f-47ac-8b9e-28fedd7e376b/the-use-of-workbook-or-workbook?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 3):

There's no big difference between the two of these.  In fact, "Workbook" inherits from "_Workbook", however, it also inherits from WorkbookEvents_Event, which provides abilities to link into workbook events.  The definition, according to my VS Metadata for "Workbook" is the following:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
{
    [CoClass(typeof(WorkbookClass))]
    [Guid("000208DA-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    public interface Workbook : _Workbook, WorkbookEvents_Event
    {
    }
}
```

- Workbooks = a collection of _Workbook objects that are currently open
  in the Excel application.
- _Workbook = an Excel workbook.
- Worksheets = a collection of all the _Worksheet objects in a workbook
- _Worksheet = an Excel worksheet

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73b4b653-cc9f-47ac-8b9e-28fedd7e376b/the-use-of-workbook-or-workbook?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: so can i use workbook instead of _workbook ?? no change in that ??

Comment: Yes you can use Workbook @keerti_h

Comment: well :) try two lines of code `((_Worksheet)ws).Activate();` and `((Worksheet)ws).Activate();`. Note: `ws` is a reference variable to an activeSheet

Comment: therefore if we're expecting general behaviour from an excel file then it looks like it is better to use `Workbook` apposed to `_Workbook` because some of the behaviour of `WorkbookEvents_Event` might be missing ?